# Tensorflow JS remove a dimension in a tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I created my first model, but the predictions are not in the right format. How I do I remove a dimension on my prediction output (or change my last layer to get the correct one)?

```js
const actualYs = [1,2,3] // The shape of my values Y

const predictions = [[1],[2],[3]] // The shape of my predictions

// My last layer looks like this:
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, useBias: true }))
```

So from my limited understanding. I could maybe remove a dimension to `predictions` or change the last layer? But I already put `1`, so not sure what else I could set it to.

In case this helps, this is my actual `console.log`

```
MY Y VALUES

Tensor
    [0.0862738, 0.0862553, 0.0861815, ..., 0.0054516, 0.0043004, 0.0037461]

PREDICTIONS

Tensor
    [[0.1690691],
     [0.1659686],
     [0.1698797],
     ...,
     [0.1118171],
     [0.1092742],
     [0.1096415]]
```

I want predictions to look like my actual Y values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reshape` or `squeeze` can be used

```
const x = tf.tensor([[1],[2],[3]] ).reshape([-1]);
// or 
const x = tf.tensor([[1],[2],[3]] ).squeeze();
```